# Goodness of regression model

Tags: regression, residuals

What are the main indicators of goodness of a regression model? Are they MSE (mean squared error) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error , R-squared and adjusted R-squared only? Can mean of absolute residual values as a fraction (or percent) of mean of dependent variable values also be a good indicator? By goodness I mean to accurately and clearly (in understandable terms) show how well the model is predicting the dependent variable.

```
mean(abs(residual_values)) / mean(dependent_variable_values)
```

Absolute may need to be taken since if large deviation occurs on both sides, the mean may still be small. This value may be more understandable than mean squared error.

Edit: I am asking in context of neural network being used to predict a numeric outcome variable after being fed a number of predictor variables. So I am more interested in knowing how accurately the network predicts the outcome variable. By 'clear' I mean that non-statisticians should also understand how well the network is predicting the outcome. In that respect the formula given above show the fractional or percent error being made by the network. Is this formula less accurate than more established measures such as R_squared or MSE?

Comment: As far as I can see you didn't really deal with *what 'goodness' is for your purposes*. What would make a fitted model better for you?

Comment: You've replaced defining 'goodness' with defining 'accurately'; that didn't resolve the lack of clarity, since you didn't really explain  what makes a model more or less 'accurate' for your purposes; without understanding your criteria it's hard to come up with 'best'. How is one to compare say MSE to some other measure without knowing what you want to achieve? (I really don't know what to make of 'clearly'; what would make a criterion unclear?)

Comment: I have tried to give more details in my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression diagnostic is well explained under this link.
I suppose you use R statistical package, after you posted a simple syntax.
Enjoy: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/rdiagnostics.html

I suggest this section:

## Additional Diagnostic Help

The `gvlma( )` function in the `gvlma` package, performs a global validation of linear model assumptions as well separate evaluations of skewness, kurtosis, and heteroscedasticity.

```
# Global test of model assumptions
library(gvlma)
gvmodel <- gvlma(fit) 
summary(gvmodel)
```

In my opinion when the assumptions are met, the model is good but maybe can be simplified. You can also look at the AIC or BIC information criterion to check whether the model couldn't be simplified to a model with fewer number of predictors. Try `step` function.

Comment: These are statistical terminology that non-statisticians are likely to find difficult to understand. Can there be some simple measure of accuracy of regression model as mentioned in my question above?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try to compute `summary` after `gvlma` function to get know if the assumptions are met. You could also look at the AIC or BIC information criterion to check whether the model couldn't be simplified to a model with fewer number of predictors. Try `step` function.